# iOS CGRectOffset and Core Data Issues

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, core-data, cgrect

I know this doesn't make any sense, but I'm getting a really strange error in an iPhone App I am building using Core Data and calling CGRectOffset. My App Delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Setup the Managed Object Context
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
if (!context) {
    // Do something - Like exit
}

//Load up the database form a pList
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tJournals" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *plistJournals = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

//Create a bunch of journals
for (NSDictionary *journal in plistJournals) {
    [TJournal journalWithDictionary:journal inManagedObjectContext:context];
}

NSError *error = nil;
[context save:&error];

// ------ Create the View Controller ------
// The Scrolling List
JournalListVC *jvc = [[JournalListVC alloc] init];

// Adjust for the Status Bar's height
CGRect viewFrame = CGRectOffset(jvc.view.frame, 0.0, 20.0);
jvc.view.frame = viewFrame;

jvc.managedObjectContext = context;

// Add the View Controller to the screen
[self.window addSubview:jvc.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Currently, the app crashes with the following error when I leave the *CGRect viewframe* line in:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'TJournal''"

If I comment out the CGRect line, it runs fine. The call inside the for loop executes just fine (it write's data to a Core Data DB entity names TJournal, and does exactly what it's supposed.) Obviously, there is no dependence on Core Data for CGRectOffset, so I'm guessing this error is spurious. But I can't, for the life of me, figure it out.

I've tried cleaning all targets, wiping out the database in the simulator, etc. But nothing seems to work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when you reference `jvc.view.frame`, it is dynamically loading jvc’s view. If the contents of the view (or xib!) have a dependency on a managed object context when it’s loaded, that could produce the error.

Try moving the `jvc.managedObjectContext = context;` line to right after `JournalListVC *jvc = [[JournalListVC alloc] init];`.

(PS: your view shouldn’t have to account for the status bar; instead, your UIWindow should do it, and then your view controller’s view’s frame should just be the window’s bounds.)

Comment: Oddly, this seems to have fixed it. Thanks!